# Error at calling jmeter function ${__time(MMddHHmmss,"variable"}

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I need the date with 10 positions but when I call the above function.

Got the error:

```
2020-08-13 12:10:12,460 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [813121012]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), abs(), wait(long), wait(long, int), max(int, int)
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [813121012]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), abs(), wait(long), wait(long, int), max(int, int)
```

Comment: It may be helpful if you reproduce the error in a code snipit and include it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts, you have 2 options:

1. Either use "Parameters" tab of the JSR223 test element

   [image]
2. Or go for generating the date [purely in Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html) like:

   ```
   vars.put('variable',new Date().format('MddHHmmss'))
   ```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: tks Dimitri, very helpful. Option 2 it's the best choose for me